# three arguments in the mat-dialog open function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, modal-dialog

how to send three arguments from mat dialog open function I want to send `dialogConfig` but compilation gives me `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.`

```
openEventModal(data?:object): void{
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

  dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;


  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EventModal,{data:data});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for sending data the dialogConfig has a function for that the function name is dialogConfig.data={}